# What is the best alternative to the deprecated lowsrc for images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to use lowsrc with the img tag to show a low resolution image first (and faster) while the larger resolution image loads.

My large resolution images are @800KB and the low res versions @50KB.

Given that lowsrc has been deprecated and many browsers do not apparently support it I am looking for a solution that does the same thing, preferably with as little code as possible.

Is there a good replacement for lowsrc?

Comment: Use the low res image as the src and replace the src onload

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Credit to @Ultimater in the comments for the suggested change to prevent an infinite requesting loop.

```
<img src="lowres.jpg" onLoad="this.src='highres.jpg';this.onload=new Function();" width="?" height="?">
```

Comment: This solution works well, except it causes an infinite requesting loop in Firefox as it causes the onload event to fire again after the src is written to. I fixed that by adding `;this.onload=new Function();` on the end though.

Comment: A user who has turned off JavaScript sees only the low-resolution image.

Comment: hi  @Ultimater   so you did this  ?  

<img src="lowres.jpg" onLoad="this.src='highres.jpg;this.onload=new Function();'" width="?" height="?">

Comment: @user3548161 You inserted my code before the single quote. My code goes after the single quote but before the double quote. You're off by one character.

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your answer to only show `<img src="lowres.jpg" onLoad="this.src='highres.jpg';this.onload=new Function();" width="?" height="?">`. I glanced at this page off a search result, used `<img src="lowres.jpg" onLoad="this.src='highres.jpg'" width="?" height="?">`, got an infinite loop in Chrome, and found that my initial attempt to make the onload a noop by `<img src="lowres.jpg" onLoad="this.src='highres.jpg';this.onload=null;" width="?" height="?">` apparently did not produce the desired behavior of only loading highres.jpg once. Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

The W3C Recommendation defining HTML5 has a list of [obsolete, nonconforming features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features), including the `lowsrc` attribute. Its recommendation is to make a progressive JPEG image whose first scan has the same level of spatial detail as the 50 kB image and whose later scans fill in the extra details in the full 800 kB image. This mechanism presumably requires user agents to use HTTP range requests to determine how much data to retrieve relative to the size at which the image is displayed, just as they use range requests to seek through the source of an `audio` or `video` element.

Answer (score 1):

I have two (three in the future) solutions:

1. Pure CSS. Will work if you only have a single placeholder image for all images being loaded. Just include a background for those images which have `[lowsrc]` property and specify some minimal height.
2. Use some JS to set the background. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyQdYJ and set `<body onload>` correctly.
3. Future. Currently not working (2015). Similar to #2, but using [attr() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) one could set the background to the value of `[lowsrc]`.

All of these solutions work with a background, which doesn't allow to specify the correct height of the image according to the height of it's background.

```
// Not working yet
img[lowsrc] {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10em;
  background-image: attr(lowsrc);
}
```

They could have kept `[lowsrc]` working :-/